# Using 3rd party jquery library with vueJS and webpack

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

I used [bootstrap-toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in Vuejs. When run the project I got an error "bootstrapToggle is not a function"

This is my VueJs Components looks like

```
<template>
  <input type='checkbox' id="toggle-checked" v-model="active">
</template>
<script type="text/babel">
  import $ from 'jquery'
  require('bootstrap-toggle')

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        active: 1
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      $('#toggle-checked').bootstrapToggle()
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

One of webpack benefits is that you can make module available in all of your files. In Vue.js we talk in components. So what you did is that you use jQuery module in you component and it will be available only in that component. To make it global add to your webpack config file:

### webpack.base.conf.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  plugins : [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $ : "jquery",
            jQuery : "jquery"
        })
  ],
};
```

simple configuration [webpack config file](https://jsfiddle.net/ppmfahd6/). Now jQuery will be available in all of your components, and now component looks cleaner:

### Vue component

```
<template>
   <input type='checkbox' id="toggle-checked" v-model="active">
</template>
<script type="text/babel">

      require('bootstrap-toggle')

      export default {
        data () {
          return {
            active: 1
          }
        },
        mounted: function () {
          $('#toggle-checked').bootstrapToggle()
        }
      }
</script>
```

This approach is good for a complex web apps with many assets such as CSS, images and other loaders, and Webpack will give you great benefits. But if is your app small Webpack will be overhead.

Comment: After edit `webpack.base.conf.js` file, I got `$` not defined.

Comment: Did you install jquery via npm?

Comment: Yes, I used _npm _ to install. Now Jquery is working fine. but bootstrap-toggle is not working until now. 
`The checkbox generated by v-for`

Comment: Does it all work now, I don't understand? Did you install bootstrap-toggle - if not type `npm i bootstrap-toggle`

Comment: [please see the link.](http://g.recordit.co/CNQpXnLGjC.gif)
this is my issue.
I have installed bootstrap-toggle using -npm-

Comment: Add    "window.jQuery": 'jquery' to your ProvidePlugin to look like this https://jsfiddle.net/re238zjx/

Comment: Also did you include bootstrap-toggle.min.css in your index.html file ->    `<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: And finally added inside nextTick
this.$nextTick(function () {
 $('#toggle-checked').bootstrapToggle()
});

Comment: @t_dom93, Seems you master vue.js. I need your help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843823/how-to-display-button-link-with-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `require` for `bootstrap-toggle`, you can add following lines in your `index.html`, which should fix this.

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```